# Floating Action button is not showing in Android Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, androidx, floating-action-button

I am new to Android and UI development. I have downloaded latest version of Windows Android studio and did some basic native UI, it worked well. Now, I am trying to develop floating action button UI.

I have added `CoordinatorLayout` inside `ConstraintLayout`. FAB is added inside CoordinatorLayout. My FAB is not visible in layout preview.

I see `androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout` text in that layout with background color. Please let me know how to fix this

**implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F44336"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are missing top constraint in `CoordinatorLayout` . also `CoordinatorLayout` should be Root View to make use of it.

Comment: Try giving 0dp to layout_height and layout_width of coordinator layout. make sure you are also setting up FAB and giving app:layout_anchor

Comment: I am planning to add RecycleView layout is  top and bottom is FAB  page

Comment: No luck. Better give me full correction code

Comment: The problem is about    `android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"` please change it to appropriate `drawable` then it works fine OR you can remove that.

Comment: no luck , I change it to android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_message_24"

Comment: This is not appropriate too!!! change it to  `android:src="@drawable/abc_vector_test"`

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F44336"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="104dp"
            android:layout_height="107dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No luck . same result :(

Comment: `android:src = "@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24" ` which refers your image source from app --> res --> drawable

Comment: What do you wish to achieve with that FAB?

Comment: It is not related to the issue, but don't use `android:backgroundTint` with the FAB. Use `app:backgroundTint`.

Comment: @Mdbasha : no luck , I see now CoordinatorLayout has full height  and don't see FAB,

Comment: Don't you see violet colored round FAB at bottom right corner?

Comment: No. I could n't see violet colored round FAB at bottom right corner

Comment: But it appears on  my end. Could you please save your project / restart Android Studio and check?

Comment: No luck, after restart also same result

Comment: You don't see it in Emulator or design layout? Try to add android:foregroundGravity="center"  for that FAB and recheck. If it doesn't work, please retry the above answer made an edit.

Comment: I restarted couple of times and able to see proper output in virtual device ( Emulator ) not in Layout . I don't know why

Comment: I think you  are viewing the Blueprint and not the Design. Try to find an Eye icon in Android Studio from the top center or surroundings of the Blueprint Layout. Above that eye icon you will see diamond shaped stack icon --> click on it to change the Blueprint to [Design] or [Blueprint + Design]. Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor#change-appearance). And I see you have no issue as the xml rendered in Emulator. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 0):

add `constraintTop` for your `CoordinatorLayout` for filling whole screen

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

or even this will be better

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

with removing all constraints

for test you may also add fixed size `FloatingActionButton`. if you want to keep `wrap_content` for FAB then ensure that `ic_baseline_add_24` is valid icon with proper size

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F44336"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

in above code `ConstraintLayout` isn't needed and you may remove it if you aren't planning to make some more complicated layout. `RecyclerView` may be placed inside `CoordinatorLayout` just before FAB - at first `REcyclerView` will be drawn, after that FAB on top of recycler

Comment: no luck , I see now CoordinatorLayout has full height and don't see FAB,

Comment: do you see `CoordinatorLayout` background color `#F44336` at full screen?

Comment: Yes, I see CoordinatorLayout background color #F44336 at full screen

Comment: `FloatingActionButton` with fixed `80dp` size isnt visible? try to put some dummy `View` with just `layout_width` and `layout_height` (both set for fixed size) and some color for recognizing is it there

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `CoordinatorLayout` with  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to contain just the FAB:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvItems"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_24px" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: No luck. Not able to see Recyleview and FAB button :(

Comment: I copied your code and don't see the above result. I don't know why ? Do u know why I am not able to add one FAB in latest Android Studio

Comment: @Gnana No idea, sorry.

Comment: I restarted couple of times and able to see proper output in virtual device not in Layout . I don't know why